# Understanding and implementing the Fast Fourier Transform

Tags: c++, fourier-transform

I need to write the fast fourier transform in C++ and I am referring to this formula from wikipedia: [image: FFT]

But for some reason I am not getting the correct output when I simply enter (1,1) (1,1) (1,1) (1,1) for by vector $v$. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
typedef complex<double> dcomp;


int main() {
    const int N = 4;
    dcomp sum1 = dcomp(0.0, 0.0);
    dcomp sum2 = dcomp(0.0, 0.0);
    dcomp *X = new dcomp[N];
    dcomp *v = new dcomp[N];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        v[i] = dcomp(1.0, 1.0);
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        for(int m = 0; m < N/2.0; m++) {
            double inside = (-2*M_PI/N)*(2*m)*k;
            sum1 = sum1 + v[2*m] * dcomp(cos(inside), sin(inside));
        }
        for(int m = 0; m < N/2.0; m++) {
            double inside1 = (-2*M_PI/N)*(2*m+1)*k;
            sum2 = sum2 + v[2*m + 1] * dcomp(cos(inside1), sin(inside1));    
        }

        X[k] = sum1 + sum2;
        cout << X[k] << endl;
    }






    return 0;
}
```

It is quite simple to read if you just look at the formula I am literally doing the same thing but my output is 
(4,4)
(4,4)
(4,4)
(4,4)

and it should be:
(2,2)
(0,0)
(0,0)
(0,0)

Can anyone help me and point out where I went wrong?

Comment: You need to write an FFT because it's been assigned to you or because you need to use such a function in your research? There are many highly optimized libraries (FFTW being the most famous) that can do this for you.

Comment: I need to do it for Homework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than having us debug your homework for you, I recommend that you read [this blog post by Jake Vanderplas](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/08/28/understanding-the-fft/) that contains a wonderful explanation of the FFT algorithm along with a highly readable Python implementation.

Comment: Great article, I have actually read it before I understand the FFT algorithm, I don't want anyone to spend time debugging my code. But I just want to know what I am doing wrong so I can fix it. I have rewritten my code over and over again and I am still getting the wrong output. Oddly enough working it out by hand I get what I want which is why I am confused that C++ does not output the correct result